# Library path is definitely correct and can create an instance of said library, but get "Undefined reference" when calling any function

Tags: c++, qt, reference, undefined, lib

I'm using Qt Creator to create a new project, and I have a test "MathLibrary" that I created in Visual Studio. I want to use this library in my Qt project.

I have searched for many hours for an answer to my solution and in almost all cases the answer was simply that the library had not been added to the PATH in the .pro file. I'm 99% sure that I have done everything correct, but something is causing me to get an Undefined Reference error when I try calling any function in this library. Here's what I have so far.

## The library -

MathLibraryH.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace MathLibrary
{
    class Functions
    {
    public:
        // Returns a + b  
        double Add(double a, double b);

        // Returns a * b  
        double Multiply(double a, double b);

        // Returns a + (a * b)  
        double AddMultiply(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

MathLibrary.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathLibraryH.h"

namespace MathLibrary
{
    double Functions::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    double Functions::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    double Functions::AddMultiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + (a * b);
    }
}
```

## The QT project -

TestQTProject.pro:

```
    QT       += core gui \
            network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TestQTProject
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

DISTFILES += \
    com_github_msorvig_s3.pri

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Libs -lMathLibrary

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Incs
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "MathLibraryH.h"

// .... other stuff ....

void MainWindow::on_btnStage1_clicked()
{
    MathLibrary::Functions lib; // This is just fine
    lib.Add(5, 9); // The "Add" function (or any other function in the library)
                       causes an undefined reference error
}
```

I'm still new to Qt but I can't see what's wrong with any of this code.

Other things I've tried based on answers from searching:

Adding the following code to MathLibrary.h:

```
#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS  
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif
```

Changing the format of the LIBS declaration in the .pro file to all of the following:

Multi-line:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Libs
LIBS += -lMathLibrary
```

Hard coded single line:

```
LIBS += -LC:\svn\software\WIP\TestQTProject\Libs -lMathsLibrary
```

Nothing I've done works and I have no other ideas left.

For what it's worth, the library works fine in any project created using visual studio, and I've tried creating both a static and dynamic library.

Comment: Change to `LIBS += -L"C:\svn\software\WIP\TestQTProject\Libs" -lMathsLibrary`

Comment: Same issue I'm afraid - the quotation marks seem not to change much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

> MATHLIBRARY_API

infront of your class name to export all public members in your dll. During export the dllexport part should be set and during import the dllimport part of course.

Here's a link that explains how to export classes from a dll:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response - by using QT's QLibrary, removing the functions from the class and wrapping them around an extern "C" block, I managed to solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to link dynamically, the problem is that your library `MathsLibrary` was not exported as a *dynamic library*, and neither you have imported it as a *dynamic library* (that's what `__declspec(dllexport)` does, and the macros should  be used at the front of functions or classes declarations to make any difference). And even if you did, there is a chance that you have compiled it differently from your Qt application, so there is a *linking* issue.

But since you are trying to link *statically* (I didn't see any library file loading at your code), the problem seems to be the diff between the compilation of your library and your Qt application.

You should try to build your *Qt Application* with the same flags and same compiler that you built your library, or vice versa. If your code is working as you say, it maybe works.

For further details:

[DL Library](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html)

[How to Create a Plugin Framework](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/building-your-own-plugin-framework-part/204202899?pgno=2)

[Building plugins using Qt Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm linking it dynamically and wrapped the function declarations and definitions around an extern "C" block and used QT's QLibrary to do what I need. Also removed the functions from the class.

It all seems to work now :)